# Turning points of a weighted cosine basis sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, summation, numerical-methods

I'm doing some work with a cosine basis, where in the interval $[0, \pi]$ some function $f(x)$ is given by

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{M} a_n \cos{\left( nx \right)} $$

For a given set of coefficients $\underline{a}$, I'm looking for a way to determine the number of turning points of $f(x)$ in $[0, \pi]$. More specifically, how many values of $x \in [0, \pi]$ satisfy

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} = - \sum_{n = 0}^{M} n a_n \sin{\left( nx \right)} = 0 $$

Assuming this can't be done analytically, does anyone have suggestions for computing this in an efficient way?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean $f_{M}(.)=\sum_{n}^{M} \ldots$ are partial sums of Fourier Series of $f(x)$?

Comment: @NgChungTak In this case cosines are being used as a complete basis on $[0,\pi]$. Any function can be represented this way with an infinite sum, but this sum is truncated to $M+1$ terms as an approximation of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's related to Gibb's phenomenon of Fourier Series.

Let's use a square wave as an example:

\begin{align*}
  f_{M}(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{M} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos (2n-1)x}{2n-1} \\
  f_{M}'(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{M} (-1)^{n}\sin (2n-1)x \\
  &=\frac{1}{\cos x} \sum_{n=1}^{M} (-1)^{n} \cos x \sin [(2n-1)x] \\
  &=\frac{1}{\cos x}
    \sum_{n=1}^{M} (-1)^{n}\frac{\sin 2nx-\sin [2(n-1)x]}{2} \\
  &=\frac{1}{2\cos x}
    \left[
      \sum_{n=1}^{M} (-1)^{n} \sin 2nx-
      \sum_{n=0}^{M-1} (-1)^{n} \sin 2nx
    \right] \\
  &=(-1)^{M} \left( \frac{\sin 2Mx}{2\cos x} \right) \\
\end{align*}

Excluding the removable singularity at $\displaystyle x=\frac{\pi}{2}$,

there are totally $2M$ zeroes:
$$x=
\frac{n\pi}{2M} \quad \text{for} \quad n=0,1,\ldots, M-1,M+1, \ldots , 2M$$

For further interest, please refer to the link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon#Formal_mathematical_description_of_the_phenomenon).